Appropriate Linear Mixed Model for nested data
I'm asking for help with the structure of a linear mixed model I'm trying to run. Here is the description of my study:
I am studying the effect of different stand types (Oak pure, Pine pure and Mixed) on the soil fungal communities (in this case, for the LMM I'm using the abundance of ectomycorrhizal fungi or shannon index as the response variable).
The experimental design is as it follows:
I have 6 locations (blocks) over the country. In each location, I have 3 plots. Each plot has one treatment (Stand type), so basically in each location I have the 3 treatments that I'm studying. Inside each plot, I took 4 samples (to have a greater sampling size of my treatments, although I know they are non-independent, and thus requiring a linear mixed model).
My objective is to compare treatments. I don't want to compare samples inside a plot. I want to compare plots, and take into considerantion that they are inside blocks (Locations).
I already have a permutation scheme using the permute package. I did this for other statistics, and I have confirmed that this permutation does satisfy my needs. Here it is:
perm <- with(data_Q, how(nperm = 999,
                         plots = Plots(strata = Plot, type = "free"),
                         within = Within(type = "none"),
                         blocks = Location))

My question is how to make a similar structure for a LMM?
Originally, I had thought of something like this:
lmer(Ectomyc ~ Stand_type + (1 + Stand_type | Location) + (1 | Location:Plot))

But since I don't want to compare samples inside a plot, I don't know if I should take out the + (1 | Location:Plot). But, at the same time, I don't know if by taking it out, I would be messing with the nestedness structure of my data (basically eliminating a level).
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
I forgot to say an important piece of information regarding this study. Each sample was collected on each quadrant of the plots (N,S,W,E), and I do have information that differentiates each quadrant (e.g. number of trees). When I say I don't want to compare samples inside a plot, I mean that I'm not interested in comparing quadrants inside a plot (due to their non-independence), only comparing different plots.

I think you definitely want to model plots as nested within Locations, which is what is accomplished by your (1 | Location:Plot) (this is also what your permute function accomplishes). On the other hand, I am not sure you want a random slope of Stand_type ((1 + Stand_type | Location), instead of (1 | Location)). My guess would be that you probably don't have enough data for it.

Thank you @David. I chose to add random slopes because I can see that the treatments have different slopes in each location (by visualizing in a scatterplot). How much data would be necessary for this?

There will always be differing treatment effects. Because no two locations are identical! Typical rule of thumb is that you need at minimum 6 groups before fitting a mixed effect model. You're right at the limit (6 locations), and I suspect you can still get away with a mixed effect model. However, I think adding random slopes on top is going to probably be too much. The model may not converge, or you will see odd things like a very high correlation between the random intercept and random slope. It could be worth fitting as a learning exercise, but don't be surprised if the results are odd.

Thank you @David, I'll take into consideration!

Let's start with your model:
lmer(Ectomyc ~ Stand_type + (1 + Stand_type | Location) + (1 | Location:Plot))

This model examines the effect of Stand_type on Ectomyc as both a fixed ("non-varying") population effect and a random ("varying") effect that differs depending on the Location Stand_type comes from. In addition, you allow for correlation in Ectomyc values drawn from the different combinations of Location and Plot with the (1 | Location:Plot) random intercept. In the language of multilevel models, you have a three level model - samples drawn from plots within the same Location. Your lmer model appropriately accounts for this structure.
Your concern is that you "don't want to compare samples inside a plot." According to your description, all the samples drawn from the same plot are of the same Stand_type (treatment). All that you (or the model) can know about samples within plot is the degree of variability in their Ectomyc values. To "compare" them, you would need to introduce another variable to the model that identified some difference in samples within plots to make a comparison. That would be something like the alkalinity of soil right next to the bark of a sample.*
Were there other types of comparisons you imagined the model making when you posted this question?
*Forgive me if this is a poor example, I'm not an ecologist!

Thank you @Erik, I did forget to say an important piece of information. Samples were collected in each quadrant of the plot (N, S, W, E), which I have discriminatory information about. For example, in one plot, samples taken in the north quadrant are being correlated with the number of trees of this north quadrant. When I said I didn't want to compare samples inside a plot is because it does not interest me to know the differences between quadrants, that is, inside a treatment (in fact, since they are non-independent, i'm afraid I can't even), only between treatments.

The current model does not make any within-plot comparisons. I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by, "For example, in one plot, samples taken in the north quadrant are being correlated with the number of trees of this north quadrant." Is this being modeled somehow that we haven't seen?

I apologize for not being able to express myself clearly. Let me try again: In each location I have 3 plots, where each one corresponds to a different treatment. In each plot, I have 4 subplots (quadrants) with one sample each (Previously, I was saying that I had 4 samples per plot, but now I'm saying that I have 4 subplots, each one with one sample). Each subplot has its own characteristics (e.g. number of trees), but are still under the same treatment (plot). (I think it's more clear now). To answer your question, when I said "stand type" as the explanatory variable, it could be anything.

Thanks for the clarification. I think your model is appropriate given your aims. I agree with @David B about you being at the limit for sample size with a mixed effect model.
